# Need the last row number which contain comment

Tags: excel, vba, comments

I'm trying to clear an entire row of cells containing a comment. So I want the last active row number which contains the comment.
I've used 
`LastRow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row`

but this is returning the last row number which contains the value.If my cell has only comment but no value then it's not giving the last row number.

Any alternative suggestion for clearing the cell comments for entire column will also welcome.

Thanks in advance.

My code to clear value is as below. I want to clear the comments as well.

```
Sub columnClear()
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim i As Long

LastRow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 3 To LastRow
Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 2).Value = Empty
Next
End Sub
```

[image: Excel ss]

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
LastRow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Comments(Worksheets("Sheet1").Comments.Count).Parent.Row
```

This is for last comment in whole sheet but I hope will be ok.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to clear either contents or comments individually in a loop:

```
Dim ws1 As Worksheet

Set ws1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
With ws1
    ws1.Range(.Cells(3, 2), .Cells(lastRow, 2)).Clear
    'clears content, comments and formatting
    'or .ClearContents, .ClearComments
End With
```

You can also obtain a `Range` reference for all the comments within a range:

```
    Set rngComments = Range("B:B").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeComments)
```

There may be a way to extract the last comment's row from this, otherwise you could loop through this range to find the max row-number.

```
Dim rngComments As Range
Dim rng As Range
Dim lLastComment As Long

Set rngComments = Range("B:B").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeComments)
For Each rng In rngComments
    If rng.Row > lLastComment Then
        lLastComment = rng.Row
    End If
Next rng
MsgBox "Last comment row for B is " & lLastComment
```